# Prove that $\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,\epsilon)|}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(z) \ ds \to f(x)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

How does one prove that 
$$\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,\epsilon)|}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(z) \ ds \to f(x) \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0^+ \ ?$$

Comment: What is $ds(z)$ in the integral?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp It's an integral over the ball surface.

Comment: It is reasonable to read your question before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you mean to divide by the volume or area or length ... of $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$. But this all works in arbitrary dimensions.

**HINT**: As usual with limits, consider
$$\left(\frac1{\text{vol}(\partial B(x,\epsilon))}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(z)ds\right) - f(x) = \frac1{\text{vol}(\partial B(x,\epsilon))}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} \big(f(z)-f(x)\big)ds.$$

Comment: Sorry. I had a few typos in the question. I edited it now. The point is: how do you pass to the limit under the integral sign and how do you obtain the result?

Comment: Don't use the limit. Use that $f$ is locally uniformly continuous.

Comment: That's unnecessarily complicated, @FriedrichPhilipp, but more or less equivalent to the standard approach. Rene: Use $|\int g(z)\,ds| \le \int |g(z)|\,ds$. But, yes, use the definition of limit and don't write limit anywhere in this argument. :) What does continuity tell you about $|f(z)-f(x)|$ when $|z-x|=\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small? [By the way, you only need continuity at $x$, not everywhere!]

Comment: Of course you have to use the continuity of $f$.